# "I've gone through" vs. "I understand"

Tags: meaning

["for IELTS speaking part two" or "for the IELTS speaking part two"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251252/115654) says

> **I've gone through** Cambridge Dictionary grammar tutorial on "A/an and the". **I guess I understand** the rules in it.

Does "I've gone through" have the implication that the speaker understands those rules?

In other words, is it a little bit wording to say something like "I understand XXX", after "I've gone through XXX", especially in writing?

Answer (score 1):

"I've gone through it" means that he has read it in its entirety (and if it had exercises to work through, he's done them all).

He guesses he understands the rules because of reading it, but is not certain because he may have missed or misunderstood parts.

Comment: Thank you. So, using those two phrases that way is not wordy at all, right?